# Is it possible to call a Rust function taking a Vec from C?

Tags: rust, ffi

Suppose I have the following Rust library:

```
// lib.rs
#![crate_type = staticlib]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn do_something(number: i32) {
    // something
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn do_something_else(collection: &Vec<i32>) {
    // something 
}
```

I know that, to call `do_something` from C, I'd just need to declare an `extern` function taking an `int32_t`, but is it possible to call `do_something_else`? If so, how?

Comment: i think you can pass integer array pointer to the rust function from C. then you can use the vector slice to do operations.

Comment: @noshusan You mean doing something like `pub extern fn do_thing(slice: &[i32])` then declare it in the C side like `void do_thing(int32_t slice[])`?

Comment: I am not sure but you can do something like `pub extern fn do_thing(slice: *[i32])` the declare it in the c side like `void do_thing(int32_t* slice[])` . Here you are using raw_pointer so you have to declare an unsafe block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *can*, but the better question is *should* you?

Since you cannot construct a `Vec` from C, you'd have to construct it in Rust and then return a pointer to C. C code would own the pointer to the `Vec` and would then pass it back when calling `do_something_else`.

Then there's the problem that you can't really modify the `Vec` in C either, other than by creating new FFI methods that mirror all of the Rust methods.

You also probably shouldn't take a `&Vec<i32>` because Rust references are **guaranteed** to not be NULL, and there's nothing that enforces that when called from C. It's better to take a `*const Vec<i32>`, assert that it's non-NULL and convert it to a reference.

Chances are that you want to accept a C array through the FFI boundary. C arrays are a pointer and a length, so you'd accept both and reconstitute a Rust *slice* (since you wouldn't own the array):

```
use std::slice;

pub extern fn do_something_else(p: *const i32, len: libc::size_t) {
    let slice = unsafe {
        assert!(!p.is_null());
        slice::from_raw_parts(p, len)
    };
}
```

Obligatory link to [*The Rust FFI Omnibus*](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/).

---

If you **really** needed to do what you asked, it would probably look something like this:

```
extern crate libc;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn make_vec() -> *mut Vec<i32> {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(Vec::new()))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add_number(vec: *mut Vec<i32>, val: libc::int32_t)  {
    let vec = unsafe {
        assert!(!vec.is_null());
        &mut *vec
    };

    vec.push(val);    
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn print_vec(vec: *const Vec<i32>)  {
    let vec = unsafe {
        assert!(!vec.is_null());
        &*vec
    };

    println!("{:?}", vec);    
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn drop_vec(vec: *mut Vec<i32>)  {
    unsafe {
        assert!(!vec.is_null());
        Box::from_raw(vec);
    }
}
```

And would be used like (untested):

```
// Add extern declarations

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *v = make_vec(); // Use a real typedef here
    add_number(v, 42);
    print_vec(v);
    drop_vec(v);
}
```

You'd want to run this under valgrind to make sure I didn't do anything stupid memory-wise.

Comment: My intention is to move some code from a C++ project into Rust -- do some computations in Rust, then get the results and use them in the C++ side. The idea is to gradually move a C++ project to Rust. What would be a better approach?

Comment: @Romário that's a difficult question to answer without knowing more and would probably be off-topic for SO. If you had C code, I might say it's worth doing this kind of change because then you could delete your hand-made expandable vector implementation. However, C++ has collections in the standard library, so you'd just be switching one standard library for the other. Perhaps you could try one level higher and move the *object* that contains the `std::vector` to Rust?

Comment: `Perhaps you could try one level higher and move the object that contains the std::vector to Rust?` Does the FFI Omnibus have any pointers on this?

Comment: @Romário probably [Using Rust objects from other languages](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/) is the closest match.